# How to validate data using JSON defined rules in C#

Tags: c#, json, validation

I have a table with some data like thins

```
     ID  FIRST  LAST    DOB
     1   Sam    Spade   1977
     2   Jane   Tarzan  1945
     3   Billy  Boinger 1984
```

Also I have a JSON file with some validation rules like this (this is just an example structure.

```
{
    "Name" : MyTable,
    "Columns" : [
        {
            "ColumnName" : ID,
            "Constraints" : [
                {
                    "type": integer,
                    "max" : 1000,
                    "Required" : true,
                }
            ]
        }
        {
            "ColumnName" : First,
            "Constraints" : [
                {
                    "type": string,
                    "maxlenght" : 100,
                    "minlength" : 3,
                    "Required" : true
                }
            ]
        }
        {
            "ColumnName" : Last,
            "Constraints" : [
                {
                    "type": string,
                    "maxlenght" : 100,
                    "minlength" : 3,
                    "Required" : true
                }
            ]
        }
        {
            "ColumnName" : DOB,
            "Constraints" : [
                {
                    "type": datetime,
                    "Required" : true,
                    "Expression": Regex
                }
            ]
        }       
    ]
}
```

I wanted to write a program in C# to validate my table data with above defined JSON rules.

Comment: This is way too broad. We're not going to write the program for you. SO is for solving specific, narrow problems, not for writing entire programs.

Comment: What have you tried? Why didnt it work the way you tried? This is not a Platform which you come to after you get a Problem, we wont do your work. Please read [How to ask a good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and update your question please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Json validation in c# is only possible if you use json.net newsoftone. [json.net intro](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Introduction.htm)

Your definition would look like this:

```
   string schemaTable = @"{
  'Name' : MyTable,
    'Columns' : {
        {
            'ColumnName' : 'ID',
            'Constraints' : {
                {
                    'type': 'integer',
                    'max' : '1000',
                    'Required' : 'true',
                }
            }
        }
           
}";
```

then you get the schema of your desired format and validate a sample json with that:

```
JsonSchema schema = JsonSchema.Parse(schemaTable);

JObject Table = JObject.Parse(@"{
  'ColumnName': '1',
  'Constraints' : [
                
                    'type': ...
                
            ]
  ...
}");

bool valid = person.IsValid(schema);
```

Isvalid function provides the verification of your json variable.